# Image quality of various Apple cinema displays

Tags: display, cinema-display

I have concluded that my office is in sore need of a new display and have decided to take the hit for one of apple's refurbished displays.  The most important thing for me is similar pixels/square inch (so that the same size font shows up the same size on each monitor).  Is there a screen-definition difference between the most recent MacBook Pros and any of the currently available cinema displays on Apple's site?  I could not find any such specs in the product descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html) calculator, I discovered that the following:

24" cinema display has 94 PPI
27" cinema display has 109 PPI
30" cinema display has 100 PPI
15.4" MacBook Pro has 110 PPI

Thus the 27" is going to be the closest PPI to my current display.